# incompatible types: string cannot be converted to date

Tags: java

Estoy intentando pasar información de una tabla de detalles a un formulario para modificar, en la fecha me sale este error en JDfecha incompatible types: string cannot be converted to date.

```
private void JTlistaempleadoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
  int seleccion = JTlistaempleado.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
   
    texid.setText(String.valueOf(JTlistaempleado.getValueAt(seleccion,0)));
    texnombre.setText(String.valueOf(JTlistaempleado.getValueAt(seleccion,1)));
    texdireccion.setText(String.valueOf(JTlistaempleado.getValueAt(seleccion,2)));
    texsueldo.setText(String.valueOf(JTlistaempleado.getValueAt(seleccion,3)));
    texpuesto.setText(String.valueOf(JTlistaempleado.getValueAt(seleccion,4)));
    texnoempleado.setText(String.valueOf(JTlistaempleado.getValueAt(seleccion,5)));
    JDfecha.setDate(String.valueOf(JTlistaempleado.getValueAt(seleccion,6)));
    
    
  
    bloquear();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Le tienes que pasar una fecha al método `setDate`, no un `String`. Utiliza [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) para convertir el string a fecha

Comment: Este tema esta muy documentado en la red , busca un tutorial de SimpleDateFormat. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/parsing-formatting-dates.html

Comment: Si ya lo busque y arregle ese pequeño problema gracias amigos.